# input element to fill remaining width of its container

Tags: html, css

This question was asked often, but none of the solutions helped we so far.
`form`'s width is set to 100%, `holder` has a relative width of 10%, now I want to fill up all the "free" width by `input_edit`. Can someone help me? Thank you!!

Here is my HTML

```
<form>
    <textarea rows="4" name="in" class="input_edit"> </textarea>
    <div id="holder"></div>
</form>
```

And my CSS

```
form {
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
} 
.input_edit {

-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box; 

width: auto;

background-color: transparent;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
border: 5px solid #666; 
margin: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
height: 60px;

float: left;

}
#holder { 
border: 5px dashed #666; 
border-radius: 5px;

margin: 5px;
width: 10%; 
height: 60px; 
float: right;
}
```

EDIT:

`holder` is 10% for now but I want it to be hidden e.g. on mobile devices so I can't work with 100-10=90%, also the problem is the `box-sizing`

Comment: @j08691 the `.input_edit` has a pixel margin and border, which makes it more difficult.

Comment: It still holds you just need to account for the difference.

Comment: @j08691 the problem is 90% won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS3 `width: calc(90% - 30px);` would work - however the number of browsers that support it is quite limited.

The next best solution is probably to manually calculate the correct width using jQuery (or JavaScript). Something like:

```
 $(".input_edit").width($("form").width() - $("#holder").width() - 40);
```

And then update it whenever the width of `form` changes.

Comment: Voted up for the CSS3 solution. It's pretty well supported in current browsers. For any new project, using the CSS solution is a lot better than the javascript option.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to remove the margin on the .input_edit and #holder, and apply box-sizing: border-box; to those elements.

Border-box puts the padding and borders in the 10% & 90%, not the margins. To get a better idea how to create gutters, I suggest you watch this video: http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/115-dont-overthink-it-grids/

I'm pretty sure that will answer a lot of your questions.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AVdLS/1/ and here's a working version of what works (no margins, though).